# Set an icon based on a condition inside a tableview javafx

Tags: javafx, imageview, tableview

I am building an application that will display an image based on a certain condition. Currently, my data are displayed in a table view on JavaFX. My observable model class contains only information about the user entered information. I need to compare the information in table view class and display image inside one of the specified column called status.

```
TableColumn<StudentRecord, ImageView> statusCol = new TableColumn<>("Status");
```

I have followed different answers but could not find a proper solution. I am doing like this to loop through all the object and display the icon. But this approach displays the icon on every rows.

```
dataController.getAllData().forEach(studentRecord -> {
                    if (studentRecord.getDate().equalsIgnoreCase("some date")) {

                        statusCol.setCellValueFactory(c -> new SimpleObjectProperty<ImageView>(new ImageView("/images/tick.png")));
                    }else{
                        statusCol.setVisible(false);
                    }
                }
        );
```

I tried different answers from StackOverflow but could not properly implement it. Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use data based on the item instead of simply ignoring the data and always returning a `ImageView` with the same image:

```
final Image image = new Image("/images/tick.png");
statusCol.setCellValueFactory(c -> {
    StudentRecord studentRecord = c.getValue();
    return studentRecord.getDate().equalsIgnoreCase("some date") ? new SimpleObjectProperty<>(new ImageView(image)) : null;
});
```

or better still to avoid recreation of the `ImageView`s use custom cells:

```
public class ImageTableCell<T> extends TableCell<T, Boolean> () {
    private final ImageView imageView;
    private final Image trueImage;
    private final Image falseImage;

    public ImageTableCell(Image trueImage, Image falseImage) {
        imageView = new ImageView();
        setGraphic(imageView);
        this.trueImage = trueImage;
        this.falseImage = falseImage;
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Boolean item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty || item == null) {
            imageView.setImage(null);
        } else {
            imageView.setImage(item ? trueImage : falseImage);
        }
    }
}
```

```
final Image falseImage = null;
final Image trueImage = new Image("/images/tick.png");
statusCol.setCellValueFactory(c -> new SimpleBooleanProperty(c.getValue().getDate().equalsIgnoreCase("some date")));
statusCol.setCellFactory(c -> new ImageTableCell<>(trueImage, falseImage));
```

---

**BTW:** I don't recommend storing dates as strings. Better use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html).